# Angular 1.5 component communicating with specific instance of sub-component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am really new to Angular and there is a particular situation I don't understand how to model.

I have a `main` component:

```
angular
  .module('synthApp')
  .component('main', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/main.template.html',
    controller: MainController
  });

function MainController() {
  ...
}
```

Its `main.template.html` file contains two instances of another component I have, the `map` component:

```
<div>
    ...
    <map name="foo">
    ...
    <map name="bar">
    ...
</div>
```

The `map` component looks something like this:

```
angular
  .module('synthApp')
  .component('map', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/map.template.html',
    controller: MapController,
    bindings: {
      name: '='
    }
  });

function MapController() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.addMarker = function(coords, classId, popupMarkup) {
    ...
  };

  $ctrl.removeMarkers = function() {
    ...
  };
}
```

The methods of `main` controller need to call `addMarker` for the foo `map` at some points, and at other points it needs to call `addMarker` for the `bar` map.

What is the best practice for a parent component communicating to a specific instance of a sub-component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either set up a pub/sub with a service or do a $rootScope.$emit('nameOfInstance', message) on the parent
and a child instance would setup a listener through $rootScope.$on('nameOfInstance', function(message){})

```
<div>
    ...
    <map name="foo" event-name="instance1" >
    ...
    <map name="bar" event-name="instance2" >
    ...
</div>
```

And in the component just add:

```
 bindings: {
      name: '=',
      eventName : '@'
    }

function MapController(){
   var $ctrl = this;
   $rootScope.$on($ctrl.eventName, function(dataFromParent) {
     // do stuff based on message
   })
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting...  It's simple but I'm wondering how scalable it is...  Because I would need to bind an event name to `addMarker`, to `removeMarkers`, and to any future methods I add.

Comment: it kind of scales if you use a channel pattern. You could have a channel per topic, users, products. Jsbin with example, https://jsbin.com/letiti/edit?html,js,console,output